# Are there any industry standards for network timeout or / IO timeout etc?

Tags: networking, timeout, io

I was reading this article about microbursts: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches/nexus-5000-series-switches/white-paper-c11-733020.html

which can also cause traffic drops.

So, as these microbursts are inevitable and can't be detected in monitoring too due to the small amount of time interval they last, is there any industry standard for timeouts on each level (I/O, network) for all applications so that we don't need to keep tuning timeout for every application?

Answer (score 1):

In a word no. Different applications are able to tolerate different latencies and different systems may have a different default "tolerance" (e.g. the maximum time that RHEL 7 gives up on an iSCSI I/O may be different to that of Windows 2012 R2 and those may be different to that of ESXi 6.5) so there's not going to be a single rule of thumb. There are opinions about latencies that are considered to indicators of bad performance though (e.g. https://blogs.vmware.com/vsphere/2012/05/troubleshooting-storage-performance-in-vsphere-part-1-the-basics.html ).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I knok proper, "real" standard-defined timeout value does not exists.

That said, some strong defaults exists:

- [UDP connections: 30/60 secs;](https://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=kb7046)
- [TCP connections: 30/60 secs for initial connection; 1800 secs for packet after connection establishment](https://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=kb7046) (note: this is strongly application-dependant);
- local SATA/AHCI/SAS: [7 secs for HBA/HWRAID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_recovery_control#Desktop_computers_and_TLER), [30 secs for Linux storage stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_recovery_control#Software_RAID);
- [iSCSI: 120 secs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/STHGUJ_7.6.1/com.ibm.storwize.tb5.761.doc/svc_iscsilinuxcfgsetting_s2zb8a.html).

Answer (score 1):

They are all tunable so you can't really rely on any default values you could probably find. Say Windows default I/O timeout is 30 seconds but this is again tunable.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/san/2011/09/01/the-windows-disk-timeout-value-less-is-better/